# AsyncTask: Implementing executeOnExecutor() thread class in AudioTrack

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, http-post, audiotrack

I am having a problem With `AsyncTask` as `executeOnExecutor()` for parallel execution, but I am getting voice with delay (400 ms to 600 ms) when sending and receiving audio. Here is my code:

The code for recording audio call:

```
private void startRecording() { 
    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
    RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
    RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, BufferElements * BytesPerElement); 
    recorder.startRecording();
    isRecording = true;
    /*
     * Schedule a task for repeated fixed-rate execution after a specific
     * delay has passed.
     */
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                bData = new short[BufferElements];

                while (isRecording) {
                // gets the voice output from microphone to byte format
                /*
                 * Reads audio data from the audio hardware for recording
                 * into a buffer.
                 */
                recorder.read(bData, 0, BufferElements);
                if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != 0) {
                    /* Send the audio voice data to server */
                    SendAudio();
                }
            }}, 0, 1);
}
```

When making call between two users, firstly initiate call take place as shown in figure.

------>>    Calling from user 1 to user 2 Initiate call = 0

If user2 receives call, Initiate call = 1 <<------

If initiate call = 1, transfer data between two users i.e. sending and receiving voice data.

------>>     When Initiate call = 1, Transfer data

Sending and receiving voice data <<------

What is the problem in playing audio data?

Getting delay in voice while playing the audio. Time between sending & receiving response is too much, approximately 400 ms to 600 ms. What do I need to do to solve this problem? Holding 5 chunks of data for the first time, when it receives the 5 audio data starts playing immediately one after the other, as shown in code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reduce the 5 audio data to 3? - not always the best idea, but it could help.
How is the bandwidth, is enough for transfer comfortably?
how is the network latency? do a ping , if there is a 400ms, than ofc you can't do much.

Comment: Thanks matheszabi, can you give me some more idea , i try with lots of way but its not work fine, my voice data is very choppy,  I chk with static with json object then its work, when i try with dynamic using local server that tine voice data goes  full duplex with very choppy, please you guide me....

Comment: for best results in Audio and Video apps you will need the NDK, and native development, which is far away to be platform independent. At this moment you have some infrastructure miss configuration, settings.